# iOS: Is there a way to use conditional segue depending on which table view cell clicked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create similar controls as the ones below the date time picker in alarm app. It appears these controls are tableview cells. I want to have several tableview cells, but when a user clicks on it, the cell's segue will take them to the View Controller of the cell clicked.

In other words, if the user clicks on the Alarm App's "Repeat" cell, the segue will take the user to the "Repeat" View Controller.

If the user clicks "Label", the cell's segue will take the user to the "Label" View Controller.

So, is it possible to have this type of conditional segue?

Any samples/links in Swift would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean segue instead of seque and sequel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` call different segue identifier

```
if indexPath.row == 0 {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage1", sender: indexPath.row)
}
else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage2", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

Then in your `prepareForSegue`, check the condition.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPage1" {
        // do something for page 1
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "showPage2" {
        // do something for page 2
    }
}
```

Your segue should drag from image below to destination controller
[image]

Comment: I created my segue by holding down control, clicking on my table view cell (prototype cell), and dragging to the destination view controller. Also, per your recommendation, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I am also doing performSegueWithIdentifier("showPage1", sender: indexPath.row).

The problem is that prepareForSegue is being hit twice. First time from the Segue created in storyboard where the sender is a UITableViewCell. The Second time is from the performSegue command within didSelectRowAtIndexPath, where the sender is an Int.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In other words, how do I ONLY enable the segue to fire from within didSelectRowAtIndexPath. How do I prevent it from being fired using it's defaults when I created it using Control Drag in storyboard.

Comment: remove the drag from cell to destination viewcontroller. now add from the yellow circle to destination controller. updated my answer @Pavel

Comment: So I can create multiple segues from the source controller to multiple destination controllers? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, should be no problem